# org mode footnotes both at the end of the page and a listing of all footnotes at the end of the document?

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to have org mode footnotes both at the end of the page and a listing of all footnotes at the end of the document?

With `#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\footnote}{\endnote}` you can create a listing of all footnotes of the document, but you don't have the footnotes in the actual page anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```org
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{endnotes}

#+LATEX_HEADER: \let\ofootnote=\footnote
#+LATEX_HEADER: \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\ofootnote{#1}\endnote{#1}}
```

This remembers the original `\footnote` definition under a different name and then redefines `\footnote` to do both the (old) `\footnote` action *and* the `\endnote` action.

I've tested this with a couple of simple footnotes in text and it seems to work. I cannot guarantee that it works in all cases however: footnotes can be somewhat complicated.